# Игнорировать неполные записи в json

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

Пользуюсь  `retrofit '2.3.0', gson '2.8.5'`

Например есть модель `ResponseData`

```
data class ResponseData(
   val name: String,
   val phone: String,
   val fullAge: Int
)
```

Бэк возвращает `List<ResponseData>`

```
[
  {
    "name": "Monga",
    "phone": "458-568-45",
    "fullAge": 2
  },
  {
    "name": null, //бэк гадина, не должен такое присылать, но присылает
    "phone": "568-45",
    "fullAge": 6
  },
  {
    "name": "Stella",
    "phone": "45677-5",
    "fullAge": 3
  }
]
```

Можно ли заставить `Gson` игнорировать те элементы `Json` которые не подходят к описанной модели?т.е. в данном примере в модели `name` указан как `NonNull`, а с бэка одна запись приходит с `name = null` - эту запись (item) нужно пропустить, в итоге чтобы получилось так

```
[
  {
    "name": "Monga",
    "phone": "458-568-45",
    "fullAge": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Stella",
    "phone": "45677-5",
    "fullAge": 3
  }
]
```

p.s. я специально не хочу создавать модель

```
data class ResponseData(
   val name: String?,
   val phone: String?,
   val fullAge: Int?
)
```

а так-же не хочу после получения и десериализации данных мапить их в другую структуру уже отфильтровывая по предикату != null

```
val domainData = list.filter { it.name != null && ... }.map { Data(...) }

data class Data(
   val name: String,
   val phone: String,
   val fullAge: Int
)
```

Comment: можно сделать так `val name: String?` и потом сделать проверку на null при парсинге данных

Comment: val name: String? - так не пойдет)

Comment: хм... у меня в обычных классах такое проходило нормально) второй вариант проверять уже после получения данных, или у вас ложится программа при попытке обработать инфо от сервера?

Comment: Работать то будет) Просто у меня вопрос в том, как в момент десериализации откидывать неполные данные(и возможно ли это сделать посредством GSON).

Comment: откидывать не получится мне кажется, я думаю лучше анализировать такого типа данные уже после обработки

Comment: ясно, было бы конечно круто) пошарусь еще по туториалам gson. Обычно так и есть, аля чистая архитектура, модель репозитория мапится в доменную модель, можно и фильтрануть.. Но тут интерес))

Comment: Предлагаю добавить маппер моделей респонза в доменную модель, в котором можно будет фильтровать невалидные модели